# Show all categories and sub category name in sidebar on product listing page

Tags: magento2, category, product-list

I'm using a custom theme in Magento 2. How can I display listing of categories and sub categories in the side bar of a product listing page.
[image]

Comment: In the title you are saying you want all categories in product page and in question you are saying in product listing page. So where do you want it exactly?

Comment: Yes I show all categories in product page, like screenshot

Comment: You can try this extension https://packagist.org/packages/sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar

Comment: I can try this extension but not categories show only - Categories in side bar. I changed configuration using admin panel but no affect. Any option using code I show siderbar